# Doubtless or doubtlessly?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

To my surprise I found that *doubtless* is used as an adverb without appending the "-ly".

> **Doubtless**, some of you will know more examples.

It *feels* wrong, but then again, I am not a native speaker. Would you use it like that, or would you substitute **doubtlessly** here?

Comment: Have you checked in a dictionary? Though they still persist in labelling 'doubtless/doubtlessly' in this usage as an adverb (/sentence adverbial). A more modern and, to my mind, acceptable classification is 'pragmatic marker subset modality'. However, single-word examples of various pragmatic markers are often of the same form as adverbs, and even as **flat adverbs** (_true_; _second_. . .).

Comment: Have you tried the explanation that's probably in a decent usage dictionary, such as *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage*? -- In my copy of *Merriam-Webster's Concise Dictionary of English Usage* (MWCDEU), there's a couple of paragraphs and usage examples for both "doubtless" and "doubtlessly" on page 279. Here's their concluding paragraph: *"The choice of 'doubtless' or doubtlessly' is the writer's. Many more of them chose the former than choose the latter."*

Comment: I fail to see how doubtlessly is redundant. Doubtless as an adverb simply doesn't sound right. To say for instance "For younger fans, the impression of seeing a real-life prince will doubtless linger longer" sounds horrible to me. It appears to be poor usage of the English language. It's a bit like how many British people are now fond of saying "bath" as a verb as in, "I bath daily" when bathe is a perfectly good word that has been around for centuries. Same goes for doubtlessly. It's a word for a reason: it's there for sentences just like the ones that are being discussed. We should use it.

Comment: 'It appears to you' to be poor usage, but is in fact correct. It has nothing to do with your usage of bath and bathe. People simply add the -ly because they think that is how it should be conjugated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Doubtless**](http://grammarist.com/usage/doubtlessly/) means *without a doubt**, so it works as an adverb (in addition to being an adjective) even though it **lacks the adverbial -ly ending**. The -ly ending in the adverb **doubtlessly** is redundant and unnecessary.

**Doubtlessly** is not wrong, but it can, and maybe should (?) be replaced with the shorter alternative. It addition to doubtless, there is the adverbial phrase **no doubt**, and there is also the slightly longer **undoubtedly**, which is more emphatic.

These writers use doubtless as an adverb:

> For younger fans, the impression of seeing a real-life prince will **doubtless** linger longer.
>
> If you asked the men involved, they would **doubtless** point to greed as the primary catalyst in this transformation.
>
> If he makes it to the run-off, he would **doubtless** find Mr Kuczynski an easier opponent than Mr Toledo.

If you want to emphasize your lack of doubt, you can use **undoubtedly**

> I saw no wildlife, although they **undoubtedly** saw me.
>
> The threats are **undoubtedly** hyperbole, but how many of our bosses would put up with them?
>
> Global warming will **undoubtedly** lead to global warring over resources.

Having said that, you will find **doubtlessly** used often enough. It's **not wrong**, it's only redundant. When in doubt, try **doubtless**.

Comment: A cunning ploy if it's the one where the food and drinks are.

Comment: Doesn't *doubtlessly* have a different (shade of) meaning? 'You will doubtless answer this question'= 'I am sure you will answer this question', while 'You will doubtlessly answer this question'= 'There you go again, answering without thinking about it'. A very subtle barb if deliberate, but unfortunate of not,

Comment: @TimLymington - if it does, I am agog.

Comment: I believe it to be redundant, unnecessary, superfluous, and extraneous, not to mention supernumerary.

Answer (score 4):

In support of Susan's answer, here is what Garner in *Modern American Usage* (p276) states:

> **doubtlessly* is incorrect for *doubtless* (a mild expression of uncertainty), *no doubt* (a stronger expression of certainty), or
>   *undoubtedly* (the strongest of these three expressions of certainty). The word *doubtless* is itself an adverb. The form *doubtlessly* is
>   therefore unnecessary.

In another entry Garner (p24) categorizes *doubtlessly* (along with *seldomly* and others) as a *NONWORD*, whose use reveals '*poor style*'.

Comment: I see the benefit of shorter words. But it also breaks the general rule for forming adverbs by appending "-ly". Such exceptions make the language more complicated for hardly any gain.

Comment: @Erwin. Yes, it would be nice if all English adverbs ended in _-ly_ (or better still, were the same as their adjective form as in German). In fact the adverb _hardly_ in your comment is one that causes difficulties, as some learners assume it is the adverb form of _hard_: _*He works hardly_!

Answer (score 1):

Using **doubtless** can make a sentence sound like it is in need of a new set of shock absorbers but it is efficient and correct and can even bring about a little subtle levity. 
For those who feel that it sounds just plain wrong, compare it with another **-ly**-less adverb, **regardless**. I've never observed anyone write or say "**regardlessly**."

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
A good answer is comprehensive and contains evidence showing why it is correct.
Links to external resources are encouraged.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].