# "Endless" as an adverb without -ly?

Tags: adverbs, flat-adverbs

My question concerns the following Siouxsie and the Banshees lyrics:

> Come let's take flight, let's quit this scene tonight
>
> Whilst they sleep on endless, in their wrecked designs
>
> Sleep on endless in your wrecked designs

Is "endless" an adverb in this case? I suspect that this usage is the same as what's discussed in this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143075/doubtless-or-doubtlessly), but I want to be sure. Another possibility I considered is that it's an adjective describing the subjects.

Comment: This is certainly an adverb (a central adverb: it modifies the verb _sleep [on]_). With the question you point to. 'Doubtless[ly]' is classically regarded as a sentence adverbial, but regarded by some as a pragmatic marker, outside the matrix sentence. 'Endless' here is an old-fashioned usage, a flat adverb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [As quick as we can?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/as-quick-as-we-can) and other questions about flat adverbs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - could you add your helpful material to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *endless* can be an adverb, as a good dictionary will tell you. The OED says it merrily serves in either role, adjective and adverb, and cites examples dating back to King Ælfred in 888 ᴀᴅ.

Here, though, is a more recent citation for your regard and appreciation:

> *Yea, one lies dead for millions dead !
>
>           On red spot in the snow
>
>   For one long damning line of red ;
>
>           **While exiles endless go**  —
>
>   The babe at breast, the mother’s head
>
>           Bowed down, and dying so !*

By Sophie Perowskaja in [*The Californian*, Volume 4](https://books.google.com/books?id=l2hZAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA107&dq=%22endless+go%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV1ZrgwKfSAhWo1IMKHUG3CpYQ6AEIRjAI#v=onepage&q=%22endless%20go%22&f=false).

Comment: Or could you add Edwin's material to your answer?

Comment: @aparente001 I think that what's going on here is that *-less* words, since they mean "without X" which can be both an adj+adv prep phrase, can also be both those as a single word. This makes more sense to me than the flat adverb hypothesis alone does.